# Manually Writing the HTML in TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi

EDIT: Look at Jorn's approach.
<strike>I am using the strategy suggested here: http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/23992</strike>  to get my HTML in the TWebBrowser, but I get a bunch of JavaScript errors when the page loads. If I click yes enough times I can see a page with no formatting and I'm guessing the page does nothing.

My theory is that because the links in the HTML are relative, the browser can't load any of it. I have switch from passing the URL, 'about:blank' to the navigate function, to passing the servers home page - in the hopes that some internal mechanism will be able to generate full paths, but no luck.

Any one successfully been able to manually write HTML to the TWebBrowser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the HTML is not coming from a live URL, you need to include a `<base href=...>` tag in the HTML itself so relative links can be resolved correctly.

Comment: This is probably exactly what I needed, but I went and got it done another way. So without checking up on it I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 10):

I usually use this approach:

```
//OnFormCreate:
begin
  WebBrowser.Navigate('about:blank');
end;

//OnButtonClick:
var
  Doc: Variant;
begin
  Doc := WebBrowser.Document;
  Doc.Clear;
  Doc.Write(Memo.Text);
  Doc.Close;
end;
```

There are also some good examples at [delphi.about.com](http://delphi.about.com/b/2004/05/27/webbrowser-to-the-max.htm)
And some more complex examples at [www.delphidabbler.com](http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=18)

Comment: Yup, thats what I ended up with, but you will probably end up seeing the same type of problems I did this way. +1 b/c this is 'better' than the method described in that article.