# Programmatically rotate tiff image (or pdf)

Tags: delphi, tiff, mshtml

Does anyone know a way of rotating an image (jpg or gif) in a TWebBrowser control (using Delphi)

**Update**

The file would be local.

**Update 2**
So I guess the question should be how do I rotate an image or pdf.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the content return in the TWebBrowser it can be done via JavaScript.

Here is an example on [JavaScript Image Rotation](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1012).

If you want to do it with a TImage there are [several options listed in this Q/A](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_2764.asp?SK=).

Comment: That JavaScript example doesn't really rotate the image.  It requires that you set up a pre-rendered set of several copies the image through multiple rotations, then it cycles through them.

Comment: Really valid point, i missed that and I can't seem to find a good example now.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you already use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784679/manually-writing-the-html-in-twebbrowser/2785046#2785046) to show the HTML content in your TWebBrowser.

Now, instead of JavaScript ([as suggested by Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190131/programatically-rotate-image-or-pdf-in-webbrowser/3190400#3190400)), you use CSS in the generated HTML document.

I haven't tested this, but you should be able to rotate the image (and other HTML-elements) by using this CSS code (for IE-based browsers):

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

See details at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532972%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Well if it's on a website (in the TWebBrowser) then you can't rotate it.  The best you can do is if the image is on your website you can use PHP/ASP/etc. to load the image, and produce a rotated version of it.

Comment: Actually.  You can download the HTML-document from the web server, parse it and manipulate it, and then show the manipulated HTML-document in the TWebBrowser.  You need tho know a little bit about the HTML-document's structure, of course... :-D