# Relative URLs in a TWebBrowser containing custom HTML code

Tags: delphi, com, twebbrowser

Using TWebBrowser, I would like to achieve following goal:

Whenever an URL ending with ".foo" is navigated, I will parse the HTML code (modify it) and then show this HTML instead.

So I am basically using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2785046) for setting the manipulated HTML code in the browser window:

```
var
  Doc: Variant;
begin
  WebBrowser.Navigate('about:blank');
  Doc := WebBrowser.Document;
  Doc.Clear;
  Doc.Write(NewHTML);
  Doc.Close;
end;
```

The problem is that the internal URL is now changed to "about:blank".

Even if I do this, the URL will be still "about:blank":

```
var
  Doc: Variant;
begin
  WebBrowser.Navigate('http://www.example.com/');
  Doc := WebBrowser.Document;
  Doc.Clear;
  Doc.Write(NewContent);
  Doc.Close;
end;
```

Therefore, all relative paths become invalid.

If the code contains for example

```
<img src="test.jpg">
```

then the browser will try to load `about:test.jpg`

So, what can I do to either:

A) change the internal URL without navigating to it

or

B) change the content dynamically during loading (without cancel the navigation)

?

Additional note:  I cannot use `Document.body.innerHTML` , because the content of a `.foo` file is not always HTML. It could also be plain text, therefore a `<body>` tag doesn't exist.

Comment: you must consume the events like onnavigatecomplete, ondocumentcomplete, .. Brian Cryer has some nice pages dedicated to [TWebbrowser](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/delphi/twebbrowser/index.htm)

Comment: I would implement ondocumentcomplete and change the html from within the event.

Comment: @whosrdaddy You mean like this http://pastebin.com/rtrp5mxY ? It still shows the "about:" prefix to all images.

Comment: I see now, you can't replace the HTML completely as you will move away from the original website. Instead you must modify the DOM  (use IHTMLElement and stuff) to do what you want.

Comment: @whosrdaddy It actually works if I edit `Doc.body.innerHTML` . But what do I do if the page is not HTML at all?

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way is to have a `<base>` tag in the HTML you generate. Doesn't fool the address bar, but does make relative URLs work.

Comment: A more advanced technique: write a custom implementation of `IMoniker` interface. You only need a non-trivial implementation of two methods: `BindToStorage` would return the `IStream` with your HTML content, and `GetDisplayName` would return the base URL you want to use to resolve relative links. You then use `IPersistMoniker` to feed the content into MSHTML using this custom implementation.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you for the hint. I already tried `<base>`, but it had several disadvantages and is a rather dirty solution. The `IMoniker` solution sounds not bad, but I have no experience about it. Can you show me how I do this, please?

Comment: Not in Delphi. I have no experience with it. [Here's](https://github.com/kuza55/csexwb2/blob/master/General_Classes/LoadHTMLMoniker.cs) a C# implementation, in case it helps (and [here's](https://github.com/kuza55/csexwb2/blob/master/cEXWB.cs#L1769) how it's used).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you very much for these links. I implemented it this way, and it works wonderfully! This is my code : http://pastebin.com/wCd4q2Zd . Can you please post your answer, so I can accept it? Also, in my code there are 4 spots marked with `// TODO` . Can you answer them, please?

Comment: *TODO #1*: You don't use `stream` for anything. I don't know why you are calling `CreateStreamOnHGlobal` at all. That whole dance is pointless.

Comment: *TODO #2*: you should return `S_OK` when queried for `IID_IStream`, and `E_NOINTERFACE` otherwise. Though I suspect you won't actually be called with any other IID, so the question is largely academic.

Comment: *TODO #3*: `IMoniker::GetDisplayName` is supposed to allocate memory for the string with `CoTaskMemAlloc`; the caller will eventually dispose of it with `CoTaskMemFree`. No idea how that is expressed in Delphi (nor really in C#)

Comment: *TODO #4*: yes, you should return `S_OK` whenever the call succeeds (and a suitable error code whenever it fails; methods you want to leave uninmplemented should return `E_NOTIMPL`). I believe C# COM binding makes all COM methods return `void`, and translates successful return to `S_OK` and a thrown exception to some error code.